# How to change formula output directly?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, text, text-formatting

I have a formula which produces some text, how do I highlight a part of the text to change the part's color?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Partial formatting can only be applied to text that is directly entered in a cell. It cannot be produced with a formula or a script.